# Div tags will not render properly

Tags: css, html, tags

So I want use multiple div tags that use webkit borders but for some reason only the one named 'Wrapper' will render. This is my code

```
.wrapper {
margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
width: 800px;
background: url('images/background_1.png');
padding: 40px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
```

And here is another sample of another tag below:

```
.body {
margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
width: 800px;
background: #fff;
padding: 0px;
border: 1px solid #fff;
font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
```

Would greatly apprec

Comment: What is it that doesn't render, the div or the border? Can you post a little bit of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: url('images/background_1.png');
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    }

    .body {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;}
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="wrapper"></div>

    <span class="body">afasfdasdf</span>
```

Comment: Did this help or have you figured it out another way?

Comment: this fixed it thank you. I am sorry I didn't mention this earlier I have been pre-occupied building a full featured forum from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with webkit, but `{ padding: 0px }` might be the culprit...?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `border-radius` declaration underneath your `-webkit-border-radius` declaration. (This is better for compatibility reasons anyway)

```
.wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: url('images/background_1.png');
    padding: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
}

.body {
    margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    width: 800px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    font: 10px "Visitor", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}
```